# I have an .obj containing UVW mapping and my assimp fail to load it

Tags: ios, .obj, assimp

I am using assimp for ios from h  t  tps://github.com/cfr/assimp-ios
these file are exported from 3d max:

- .obj
  h  t  t  ps://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Nuhl0WqfMjMUF5cks2YmR2Rlk/edit?usp=sharing
- .mlt
  h  t  t  ps://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Nuhl0WqfMjMmtSSVZyYV85b3c/edit?usp=sharing

I import the file with this statement:

```
NSString* path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/unicity04_low_full2.obj"];
aiScene = aiImportFile([path cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] ,aiProcessPreset_TargetRealtime_MaxQuality);
```

with no error report from aiGetErrorString()
then i check imported data by logging value in

```
aiScene->mMeshes[n]->mNumUVComponents[0]
aiScene->mMeshes[n]->mTextureCoords[0][k].x
aiScene->mMeshes[n]->mTextureCoords[0][k].y
aiScene->mMeshes[n]->mTextureCoords[0][k].z
```

(where n and k is index of particular mesh and vertex)

The result is

- mNumUVComponents[0] is 2 for all value of n
- mTextureCoords[0][k].z is 0 for all value of n and k  However
- mTextureCoords[0][k].x, mTextureCoords[0][k].y is correct according
  to .obj

  for example, 1st texture coordinate for 1st object in .obj is vt
  -248.0264 1000.0000 50.0000 the respective logging show that:
- mNumUVComponents[0] is 2
- mTextureCoords[0][0].x is -248.0264
- mTextureCoords[0][0].y is 1000.0000 mTextureCoords[0][0].z is 0